# Preventing multiple QR code scans

Tags: security, qr-code

I've been thinking of a way to ensure that a QR code could be scanned only once.

Let's take an imaginary situation for example, you go to a store, and if you buy stuff worth 20€ or more, the cashier shows you a QR code which you can scan with a dedicated mobile app to get a discount coupon for later use. The app would collect all the coupons from all participating stores. So the code would essentially contain the store id and the discount id.

The problem is, how to make sure a user can't scan the code repeatedly to get multiple coupons when he is only entitled to 1 at a time? The code can't be one time only per user, because he can come back again later, buy more stuff and be eligible for another coupon.

The user could also possibly scan the code with another QR code reader, get the store and discount id and create their own identical QR (or just take a picture of the QR at the counter), and then scan that at their home for unlimited discounts. Any thoughts on how to prevent these kinds of problems programmatically?

Most secure way I can think of is to guard the QR well and only let the cashier scan the code with your phone, but that's not very fancy.

Comment: The solution is to not use, or accept, the same QR (or other) code more than once. There is no programmatic means of identifying a single individual, thank goodness.

Comment: The only solutions involve centrally recording scans and checking whether a unique ID has been scanned before. There is no way to do this just within the barcode technology.

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem I'm working on, here's the solution I've come up with.

1. Cashier displays a QR code on the screen.
2. User scans the code.
3. The app deciphers the code and sends a message back to the server saying which code it scanned.
4. The server contacts the Cashier's screen, and instructs it to turn off (or display a different message etc.)

The alternative is to make the app responsible for policing which codes it scans.  For example, if you have a coupon `abc123` the app should keep a record that it has already been used on that phone, and disallow any future use.